# Azupre Pipelines + Github + Can't create CHECKS for pull requests

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a new Pipeline at `dev.azure.com`, I have linked to the github repo, and even got triggered on a new Pull Request is created. **BUT** I can't get a new check for that branch:

[image]

PR: trigger is activated and working:
[image]

Also the CI is activated:

[image]

And the web hooks are created in github:

[image]

Summary: I don't know how to link OR create a new check that appears as selectable at github branch configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final goal was getting a check for using it at pull request verifications. I'm new in this of CI. After some research, I notice that in the dev.azure pipeline the connection to git hub had the same name as one of the available checks in GitHub branch configuration. So, I mark that check. In this case what happened was that it created a new check when PRs were done, but this check never got updated.

I think there are other configurations options that I actually don't know well. It seems to be related to the fact that in the repo should be a yml file with the pipeline configuration or something like that.

**SOLUTION** (for me): After talking with a friend of mine, he suggested NOT using azure pipelines for branches/PR validation. Instead, he suggested using Github Actions. That was the solution. After playing a bit with this GitHub actions (runtime versions, running paths, etc.) I got it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If your pipeline doesn't show up in this list, please ensure the following:

- **You are using GitHub app authentication**
- Your pipeline has run at least once in the last week

If you're using [**GitHub app authentication**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#github-app-authentication) for your Azure Pipelines integration with GitHub, you can use your pipeline's build results with GitHub Checks to help protect your branches.

Besides, to configure mandatory validation builds for a GitHub repository, you must be its owner, a collaborator with the Admin role, or a GitHub organization member with the Write role.

More detail info please refer our official doc here-- [GitHub Checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#github-checks)

Comment: About all the things you are pointing in the answer, all are yes: 1) using github auth 2) pipelines have run at least once 3) I'm the owner. I think is something I'm missing.